# Unable to navigate the page in FrayxRulez/SwipeListView control in windows phone 8.1

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8.1, swipe

I am working with windows phone 8.1 c# application . I want swpe to delete control so I have used [FrayxRulez/SwipeListView](https://github.com/FrayxRulez/SwipeListView) it working fine but when i used SwipeListView_ItemClick event it doesn't navidate to another page .

```
private async void SwipeListView_ItemClick(object sender, ItemClickEventArgs e)
{
    var item = e.ClickedItem as EmailObject;
    Frame.Navigate(typeof(TestPage));
     // await new MessageDialog(item.Body, "Clicked Item").ShowAsync();
}
```

It caused crashed .
Please help me out for that .

Answer (score 0):

I've just tried and it works with a new XAML BlankPage. So your crashed is caused by something in your TestPage. Check exceptions in Debug mode when you navigate in TestPage, or use some breakpoints.